# Accelerated mobile pages in django?

Tags: django, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Are any Django developers working on building out AMP-HTML pages?

(For reference: [Google AMP-project](https://www.ampproject.org/))

If I understand it correctly, the way AMP-HTML works is, you create 2 separate files for each page.  The normal HTML result, plus a new AMP-HTML file.  The AMP-HTML file is a slimmed-down version of the normal HTML page, and is used by Google to return an accelerated mobile page (hence the name, "Accelerated Mobile Pages").  Each of these files then reference each other in a  tag in the head, which tells Google to use the AMP file for mobile results.

Within the Django framework, I'm wondering how to create 2 separate files based on the same set of content.

How might it be possible to make use of a single context that could be passed along to two HTML results?  One result being the normal HTML page, the other being an AMP-HTML page.

In Django a URL must be created for each page to be returned.  How might a second URL be automatically generated for each existing URL?  Additionally, how can a single context be called up for each of those URLs?

Could it be done in the view perhaps?  Such as, returning an .html extension which is the AMP page, and then also rendering the template for the URL?

I don't have any answers yet on how to tackle this.  Looking for feedback and suggestions.  It appears this is the first-ever question posted to stackoverflow on Django and AMP-HTML.  It is likely to not be the last.

Comment: Maybe you could use a middleware to detect which template to use, i would need to check the amp-html project to see how it is supposed to work,

Answer (score 6):

I am a fellow django AMP developer but definitely not an expert, we are using the following url pattern

```
url(r'^api/news/', include('news.api_urls'), {"type", "regular"}), # regular

url(r'^api/amp/news/', include('news.api_urls'), {"type": "amp"}), # AMP
```

and in the view generating different context to be passed to the templates, canonicals in the templates point to each other and it seems to work

Comment: Couldn't you just use a single `url` as in: `url(r'^api/(:?(?P<type>amp)/)?news/` and the view would have a `type='regular'` keyword argument so that when the regex matches the `type` group you end up passing `type='amp'` and when it doesn't match the view gets `type='regular'`.

Comment: @Bakuriu that seems like a more efficient way of doing it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

In the view, you can set the template variable in a number of different ways, like in a GET query parameter:

```
if request.GET.get('amp', 0) == 1:
    template_name = "amp.html"
else:
    template_name = "regular.html"
```

You can pass `template_name` as variable into the context, which you can then use when rendering the page:

```
{% extends template_name %}
```

That will allow you to render two entirely different layouts using the same view code/urls/context.

Answer (score 4):

I create app https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-amp-tools  for this

`{% load amp_tags %}`  in template

`{% amp_canonical_link request %}` in meta

and create "amp" folder in templates

it's first release. more documentation and futures will be added

Answer (score 1):

Just to improve the first answer, i am providing a more detailed example.

**project/urls.py**

```
url(r'', include('app.urls'), {"type": "regular"}),
url(r'^amp/', include('app.urls'), {"type": "amp"}),
```

**app/urls.py**

```
url(r'^home/$', views.home),
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request,type):
    if(type=='amp'):
        return render(request, 'app/amp/page.html', {}) 
    else:
        return render(request, 'app/page.html', {})
```